# -webkit-appearance: button; but for Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox

Is there a way in firefox to hide all of a select list's styles? Ive done it for webkit browsers with -webkit-appearance: button;

Ideally id like solutions for all browsers, but Firefox and Webkit are the most important for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add these to do it in all browser:

```
appearance: button;
-o-appearance: button;
-ms-appearance: button;
-moz-appearance: button;
-khtml-appearance: button;
-webkit-appearance: button;
```

Comment: I had to change the moz style to this to make it disappear: -moz-appearance: checkbox-container;